# Any point in using ES6 Map when keys are all strings?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript, es6

Plain object keys must be strings, whereas a `Map` can have keys of any type.

But I have little use for this in practice. In nearly all cases, I find myself using strings as keys anyway. And presumably `new Map()` is slower than `{}`. So is there any other reason why it might be better to use a `Map` instead of a plain object?

Comment: [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map#Objects_and_maps_compared), as usual, has a good comparison.

Comment: FYI, Map [appears to be faster](https://jsperf.com/es6-map-vs-object-properties/2) for both setting and getting.

Comment: @mpen – jsperf is down now. Are you sure `map.set('foo', 123)` performed quicker than `obj.foo = 123`? If so that's very surprising

Comment: @callum Uhh..no, not positive. You might want to write some new performance tests.

Answer (score 56, accepted):

There are some reasons why I prefer using `Map`s over plain objects (`{}`) for storing runtime data (caches, etc):

1. The `.size` property lets me know how many entries exist in this Map;
2. The various utility methods - `.clear()`, `.forEach()`, etc;
3. They provide me iterators by default!

Every other case, like passing function arguments, storing configurations and etc, are all written using plain objects.

**Also, remember:** Don't try to optimize your code too early. Don't waste your time doing benchmarks of plain object vs Maps unless your project is suffering performance problems.

Comment: What's the identity hashcode function used by Javascript?

Comment: @Pacerier `===` :)

Comment: Maps are much faster than plain objects these days.

Comment: @gustavohenke That's not true. `Map` uses the SameValueZero algorithm. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Equality_comparisons_and_sameness

Comment: @lolmaus-AndreyMikhaylov okay, but did I say something about `Map`s using this or that?

Comment: @gustavohenke You said it's `===` whereas it's SameValueZero in the context of the question.

Comment: @lolmaus-AndreyMikhaylov Well that's arguable. The person didn't ask _explicitly_ about `Map`s.

Answer (score 5):

I'm not sure about this, but I think that performance is NOT a reason to use Maps. Take a look at this updated jsperf page:

http://jsperf.com/es6-map-vs-object-properties/73

It looks like (when dealing with strings at least) objects are much faster than maps for basic setting and getting.

EDIT: this answer is now outdated and wrong. See comment stream below.

EDIT2: Oddly, after all of the comments, it seems to return to Object being faster than Map (at least when storing numeric values).
https://jsperf.app/es6-map-vs-object-properties/243

EDIT 3: It turns out JS optimizes everything when using a key that looks like a number, even if it was created as a string. When I use `key_${i}` rather than just `${i}` for the key, things turn out much differently. Compare the flawed test above to this corrected version:
https://jsperf.app/es6-map-vs-object-properties/251

Comment: That's not how you write performance tests.

Comment: That's not how you write useful comments. Please feel free to elaborate if you have an alternate methodology to suggest. What, specifically, is wrong with how those tests were written? Are they in any way invalid or unhelpful?

Comment: Language semantics/constructs being tested via microbenchmarks must only differ by one variable. Your tests vary across number of iterations, and a few of them will have their inner loop contents optimized out since the result is unused. Some tests pre-declare variables while others have the variable declaration inline with the for loop - which may incur different performance abnormalities.

Comment: Ouch, you're absolutely right. In my defense, the my version was an improvement on the one before it, but I missed both the pre-declare and the inner loop contents being optimized out. I was working with a colleague who improved upon my draft and I think resolved those issues: https://jsperf.com/es6-map-vs-object-properties/88. However, I think that it's valid to have different loop styles for the different data structures; in real usage, people will choose the loop structure with the best performance, and Map and Object have different "optimal" loop structures. Anyway, thanks for the catch.

Comment: Ok I see now - they used to be slower than plain objects, but have been heavily optimized in recent browsers.

Comment: Objects can never be as fast as Map. The runtime has to support prototypal inheritance & key mapping (e.g. numbers are converted to strings) that make optimizations complicated and bring overhead. Where as Map is just a straight forward key, value store that can be optimized to the extreme

Comment: Unfortunately jsPerf seems to not be editable anymore, so I can't revise the tests to do a fair comparison, but I think at this point everyone would have to agree with you. When I originally wrote this answer, maps were actually slower than objects because maps were newer and not optimized. But since then they do seem to have caught up to and surpassed objects, based on tests I've run in real-world settings.

Comment: It appears that jsperf has been updated: [https://jsperf.com/es6-map-vs-object-properties/241](https://jsperf.com/es6-map-vs-object-properties/241)

Comment: And interestingly, people are still making the same mistakes I did initially. I just updated the test to actually use the result so the body of the loop isn't optimized away, and amazingly... object is still faster than Map! https://jsperf.com/es6-map-vs-object-properties/243

Comment: Map is way faster than object, both in Firefox and Chrome/Node https://jsben.ch/GdMb7

Comment: Your jsben.ch link takes me to malware sites, even though it used to work. But anyway, your test tests both writing and reading in a single test, which is only useful if you will do both operations frequently. For reading only, it seems Object is still faster then Map, unless you can see something wrong with my test here (note update from jsperf.com to jsperf.app) https://jsperf.app/es6-map-vs-object-properties/243

Comment: Oh! My benchmark was very broken in a subtle way - I thought `${i}` would give me a string representation of i, but JS was being too smart and converting back to a number when I used it as a key, and optimizing as if I were using an array instead. Here is an updated benchmark that better shows the difference between using string keys or numeric keys for both Map and Object: https://jsperf.app/es6-map-vs-object-properties/251

Answer (score 4):

The other answers don't mention one last difference between objects and `Map`s:

> The `Map` object holds key-value pairs and **remembers the original insertion order of the keys**.
>
> Thus, when iterating over it, a Map object returns keys in order of insertion.

*Quote from [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map), **emphasis** mine*

---

This was the main reason I decided to use `Map` for the first time in a recent project. I had a normal object that I needed to display in a `<table>`, with each property going in a specific row.

```
let productPropertyOrder = [ "name", "weight", "price", "stocked" ];

let product =
{
    name: "Lasagne",
    weight: "1kg",
    price: 10,
    stocked: true
}
```

I wrote a function to transform an object into a `Map` according to a desired key order:

> **Note:** this function discards all object properties not found in `order`

```
function objectToMap( obj, order )
{
    let map = new Map();

    for ( const key of order )
    {
        if ( obj.hasOwnProperty( key ) )
        {
            map.set( key, obj[ key ] );
        }
    }

    return map;
}
```

Then the map could be iterated over in the desired order:

```
let productMap = objectToMap( product, productPropertyOrder );

for ( const value of productMap.values() )
{
    let cell = document.createElement( "td" );
    cell.innerText = value;
    row.appendChild( cell );
}
```

---

Of course this is a bit contrived because one could just as well display when iterating over the property order without creating a `Map` in the process:

```
for ( const key of productPropertyOrder )
{
    if ( product.hasOwnProperty( key ) )
    {
        let value = product[ key ];
        // create cell
    }
}
```

But if you have an array of such objects and are going to be displaying them many places, then converting them all to maps first makes sense.

Comment: Your function `objectToMap` is reducing; every entry in the object whose key isn't in `order`, gets omitted from the resulting map. You might wanna include this information in your answer.

Comment: Objects _also_ preserve the original insertion order of keys... [mostly, but with some caveats](https://tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-ordinaryownpropertykeys): "array index" keys (which are those satisfying `\`${key>>>0}\` === key`) are always listed first, in numerical order, then all string keys in original insertion order, and then all symbol keys in original insertion order.